# I want to use ctrl+f command with search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ctrl, ara

I want to use a search like Ctrl+F in Virtual Tour work. First of all, the address of this study is [360franke.com](https://360franke.com)

I have a single index.html file. Almost all work,

```
    <body>
      <div id="viewer" class="fill_viewport"></div>
    </body>
```

It is displayed with this div.

I can find the menu items (eg. Konseptler, Katalog) with ctrl+f in the browser. But I want to redirect it with a search button, not ctrl+f. Many methods I have tried have not worked. Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. I'm not sure what "I want to redirect it with a search button, not ctrl+f" means.

Comment: Additionally, we cannot tell you what did not work with the methods you tried if you don't tell us what you tried.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to capture event and focus the search bar

This code redirects ctrl + F, cmd + F and F3 to an input

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code === 'F3' || ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.code === 'KeyF')) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    const search = document.querySelector('#search')
    search.focus()
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="search">
```

Comment: This looks very ingenious. But the search bar did not work. What could I be missing?

Comment: https://360franke.com/search_test.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can't override the default browser <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> functionality; however, a common implementation of this is with <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> instead (see [this website](https://mui.com/)).

Take a look at this demo:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const search = document.querySelector('input');

// Our epic dummy dataseet
const items = [
    {
        title: 'foo',
    },
    {
        title: 'bar foo',
    },
    {
        title: 'baz',
    },
    {
        title: 'fizz buzz',
    },
    {
        title: 'baz foo bar',
    },
    {
        title: 'baz bar',
    },
    {
        title: 'buzz foo',
    },
    {
        title: 'foo buzz',
    },
];

// Takes an array and populates the list with
// all the elements
const populateItems = (arr) => {
    ul.innerHTML = '';

    for (const { title } of arr) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = title;

        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
};

// Display the search bar
showSearch = () => (search.style.display = 'block');

// Hide the search bar
hideSearch = () => (search.style.display = 'none');

const handleKeyDown = ({ key, metaKey, ctrlKey }) => {
    // Continue only if they are pressing CMD + K
    if (!((metaKey || ctrlKey ) && key === 'k')) return;

    // If search is already shown, hide it
    if (search.style.display === 'block') return hideSearch();

    // Otherwise, show it
    showSearch();
    search.focus();

    // Add a listener so that when use clicks out of the
    // search bar, it will disappear
    const handleClickOut = ({ target }) => {
        if (target === search) return;

        hideSearch();

        // Remove the event listener after it's been fired
        window.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOut);
    };

    window.addEventListener('click', handleClickOut);
};

// Filters the elements and repopulates
const handleSearch = ({ target }) => {
    // If empty string, just repopulate with the full list
    if (!target.value) return populateItems(items);

    // Else, filter and repopulate with filtered items
    const filtered = items.filter(({ title }) => title.includes(target.value));
    populateItems(filtered);
};

search.addEventListener('keyup', handleSearch);
window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => populateItems(items));
```

```css
input {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
<input type="search" placeholder="Search for an item..." />
```

Keep in mind that between Mac and Windows, the key people are used to using is different. On Mac, we use <kbd>CMD</kbd>, while Windows uses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, so we've covered both cases here.